# When I reload my game scene the objects do not reload in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    Scene scene;
    private void Awake()
    {
        scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
    }

    public void LoadScene(string level)
    {
        if (level == "Game")
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");

        }
        else
        {
            UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(level);
        }
    }
}
```

When it reloads the game scene the objects are stationary like when they were when the scene finished.

Comment: Use this after LoadScene DestroyObject(GameObject.Find("ObjectsToBeDestroyed"));

Answer (score 2):

What you do is supposed to work.

The only objects that are not reloaded are those that have a script containing `DontDestroyOnLoad`. You should check if this is the case for your objects

By the way, your if-else blocks are useless, they do the same thing as if you wrote

```
public void LoadScene(string level)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(level);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the objects are showing in the Scene view but not in the hierarchy, you should check if the scene is collapsed. If so, click the arrow to the left of the scene name.